# What exactly is the difference between the PPP ("purchasing power parity") and LOOP ("law of one price")?

Tags: macroeconomics, exchange-rates, purchasing-power-partity

For PPP & LOOP: e = EP/P* = 1
So both are valid if goods in the US and EU cost the same in $ for example.
But then, what exactly is the difference between both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPP uses the price level, the price of the consumer basket. The price level can be identical without all prices being identical. An example:

Consider a consumer basket with just two goods and assume the weight of both goods in the basket is one half. If $p_1 = p_2 = 4$ then the price of the consumer basket is
$$
P = \frac{1}{2} \cdot p_1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot p_2 = 4.
$$
However you get the same price level if you have $p_1 = 3,  p_2 = 5$.

So you can have two countries with identical price levels but differing prices. The converse of course is not possible. Thus LOOP implies PPP but PPP does not imply LOOP.

Comment: So as consequence:
LOOP requires identical prices and price level and PPP just identical price levels?

Comment: @visionInc Factoring in the exchange rate, yes.